# Sencha touch dataview eventhandler for item

Tags: extjs, touch, dataview

**Platform: Sencha Touch 2.1**

I am trying to call an event on tap of of the items from the dataview but being a newbie cannot figure it out.

```
 {
    xtype: 'dataview',
    cls: 'ownprofile-top',
    itemId: 'profileOptions',
    store: { fields: ["name", { name: "optionsButtons", type: 'string' }],
    data: [
        { name: 'First Option', event: 'onFirstBtnTap' },
        { name: 'Second Option', event: 'onSecondBtnTap'},
        { name: 'Third Option', event: 'onThirdBtnTap'}
    ]
    },
    scrollable: null,
    cls: 'profile-item',
    itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '{name}'
    )
}
```

So on tap of either of the options, I want an event to fire or call another method to do xyz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listener to [itemtap](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-event-itemtap)

```
{
    xtype: 'dataview',
    cls: 'ownprofile-top',
    itemId: 'profileOptions',
    store: { fields: ["name", { name: "optionsButtons", type: 'string' }],
    data: [
        { name: 'First Option', event: 'onFirstBtnTap' },
        { name: 'Second Option', event: 'onSecondBtnTap'},
        { name: 'Third Option', event: 'onThirdBtnTap'}
    ],
    listeners: {
       itemtap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
           //Do xyz
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: is itemtap a system method? How would my dataview listen to this unless it has any reference to the itemtap?

Comment: itemtap is an event thrown by your dataview when an item is tapped. It's in the docs: `Fires whenever an item is tapped` click [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-event-itemtap) for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

may be, you need in use listener? http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addListener